# Infragistics cells rollover time frame increase

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an Infragistics UltraGrid control. When I hover over a cell in the grid, it displays the contents of the cell as a tooltip for about 5 seconds. I want to increase this timeframe. I tried to override that property(`AutoPopupDelay`) but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code as discussed on the [Infragistics forum](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/77887/393116.aspx). You'll want to replace the `ToolTipText` with the cell's value, but I assume your code already does that.

C#:

```
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.TipStyleCell = TipStyle.Hide;

if (e.Element.GetAncestor(typeof(RowUIElement)) != null) {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(e.Element.GetType, typeof(RowAutoPreviewUIElement))) {
        ToolTipInfo.ToolTipTitle = "Row Warnings";
        ToolTipInfo.ToolTipText = "Your cell value";
        UltraToolTipManager1.SetUltraToolTip(UltraGrid1, ToolTipInfo);
        UltraToolTipManager1.ShowToolTip(UltraGrid1);
}
```

}

VB.NET:

```
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.TipStyleCell = TipStyle.Hide

If e.Element.GetAncestor(GetType(RowUIElement)) IsNot Nothing Then
    If e.Element.GetType Is GetType(RowAutoPreviewUIElement) Then
        ToolTipInfo.ToolTipTitle = "Row Warnings"
        ToolTipInfo.ToolTipText = "Your cell value"        
        UltraToolTipManager1.SetUltraToolTip(UltraGrid1, ToolTipInfo)
        UltraToolTipManager1.ShowToolTip(UltraGrid1) 
    End If
End If
```